# Performance implications of hoistServer with a "dynamic" runApp function?

Tags: performance, haskell, servant

My webserver is written in an `AppM :: ReaderT Env IO` monad. The `Env` type, for the purpose of centralized auditing code, needs to know the request's path. Therefore, my `hoistServer` usage looks something like this:

```hs
\req respHandler -> 
  let application = serve apiProxy $ hoistServer apiProxy (\appm -> runAppM req appm) myServer
  in application req respHandler
```

Notice how the second argument to `hoistServer` depends on the incoming `req`.

What are the performance implications of doing something like this? Is the servant application going to get "re-created" for every incoming request?

Is there any other way to possibly write this code to make it more performant?